# PHP - Switch, case, and "go on" - multi choice generic then specific

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

Is there a way to do the common treatment then the specific one **without** using another switch case ?

```
switch ($var) {
  case 'A' :
    /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 1 */
    break;
  case 'B' :
    /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 2 */
    break;
  case 'C' :
  case 'D' :
  case 'E' :
    /* GENERIC, COMMON TREATMENT */
    // go on, check again $var ! :(
  case 'C' :
    /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 3 */
    break;
  case 'D' :
    /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 4 */
    break;
  case 'E' :
    /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 5 */
    break;
  case 'F' :
    /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 6 */
    break;
  default :
    /* DEFAULT TREATMENT */
    break;
}
```

In order to avoid duplicate code, it will be really efficient... Using another Switch() in the first one is something I would like to avoid. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cases = array('A','B','C','D');
if (in_array($var, $cases)) {
    /* GENERIC, COMMON TREATMENT */

    switch ($var) {
        case 'A' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 1 */
        break;
        case 'B' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 2 */
        break;
        case 'C' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 3 */
        break;
        case 'D' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 4 */
        break;

    }
} else {
    /* DEFAULT TREATMENT */

}
```

Based on your subsequent edit, I'd maintain the same approach

```
$cases = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G');
if (in_array($var, $cases)) {
    $common = array('C','D','E');
    if (in_array($var, $common)) {
        /* GENERIC, COMMON TREATMENT */
    }
    switch ($var) {
        case 'A' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 1 */
        break;
        case 'B' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 2 */
        break;
        case 'C' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 3 */
        break;
        case 'D' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 4 */
        break;
        case 'E' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 2 */
        break;
        case 'F' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 3 */
        break;
        case 'G' :
            /* SPECIFIC TREATMENT 4 */
        break;

    }
} else {
    /* DEFAULT TREATMENT */

}
```

Comment: Not so bad at all ! But I'll choose @kolink answer, because in my case, some of the case have no generic treatment to do. I'm editing one more time. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Erm...

```
$txt = "You pick the letter ".$var;
```

Perchance?

Comment: Nononono it was just a example, I can't do it ^^

Comment: @Ash_: What do you mean "can't do it"?

Comment: Surely if you're able to compare it for the purposes of the `switch`, you can do it? Unless you wanted to display something other than the comparison operand?

Comment: I'm sorry I miss-explained myself. Check the code again, if you mind

Answer (score 3):

```
    $txt = "you picked the letter ";
    $var = 'C';
    switch ($var) {
      case 'A' :
        $txt .= "A";
        break;
      case 'B' :
        $txt .= "B";
        break;
      case 'C' :
        $txt .= "C";
        break;
      case 'D' :
        $txt .= "D";
        break;
      default :
        $txt = 'you didnt pick A or B or C or D';
        break;
    }
    echo $txt;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$common = function() use (&$var) {
    // do stuff that is common to several cases
};
switch($var) {
    case 'A':
        $common();
        // now specific stuff
        break;
    case 'B':
        $common();
        // specific
        break;
}
```

And so on. You still get the repetition of `$common()`, but at least it's less than what you probably want to do.

Comment: Cute. I think this is mostly what I want. (editing my post again)

Answer (score 0):

```
$var='c';
$arr=array('A'=>'xxx',B=>'xxxxxx'.......);
echo 'some you want '.$arr($var);
```